# Metric with singularities on Riemann Surfaces and the associated Laplacians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I have asked this question on Math Stack Exchange

[Metric with singularities and associated Laplacian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143232/metric-with-singularities-and-associated-laplacian)

but I have not got any answers/comments, therefore I post this question on the MO.

Suppose $M$ is a compact Riemann surface, and $g$ is a metric on $M$ with finitely many singular points. For simplicity let us impose further restrictions on $g$, and we suppose in every local neighborhood with coordinate $z$, $g$ is of the form
\begin{equation}
g=f(z)\overline{f(z)}dz d\bar{z},
\end{equation}
where $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function with a power series expansion 
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\sum_{m\geq N} a_{m}z^m , N \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{equation} 
We say $g$ is singular at the point $z=0$ if the series expansion of $f$ has negative powers. In particular we have excluded the case where $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. With respect to such a metric, we can still define the associated Laplacian operator $\Delta$ on the smooth locus of $g$.

My question is, are there any results about the spectrum of such a Laplacian? In particular, is it bounded from below? References are welcomed.

Comment: The smooth part is not compact. You need some boundary conditions to define a reasonable spectrum of Laplacian. Without them it may be non-discrete)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Do you know of any references about what boundary conditions give reasonable spectrum?